# how can i connect to a mongodb from Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

how can i connect to a mongodb from Ruby code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kir's answer is appropriate if you are working only with Ruby. But if you are developing a Rails app, you likely will want to connect to MongoDB with an ORM such as:

- [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)
- [MongoMapper](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper)

Using an ORM will give you the functionality Rails developers are familiar with in ActiveRecord. See a list of [MongoDB Clients](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/mongodb_clients.html#mongoid_mongoid) on http://ruby-toolbox.com/.

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, you have to install MongoDb gem:

```
gem install mongo
```

Then run code:

```
require 'rubygems'  # not necessary for Ruby 1.9
require 'mongo'
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb") # OR
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost").db("mydb") # OR
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost", 27017).db("mydb")
```

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center
- http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

Short version: install the Mongo gem, then `db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")`

Comment: As a side note, these were Google search results #1 and #2 for "mongodb ruby".